# how to recover a wampserver root folder from git

Tags: database, git, web, wampserver, recover

I was working on a project that i kept in wampserver root folder. I used a local git repository to save every step of the work. at some point I forgot that the files were inside wampserver and I deleted wampserver to install it again when it was stuck. the folder is not kept in recycle bin too. is there a way I can recover my whole project folder from the last git commit?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if that local Git repository was pushed anywhere (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, ...) or not.

Because if that local repository was not pushed or cloned, then it is a simple local set of files, deleted when the wampserver was deleted.
In which case, only some file/data recovery software would be your only approach.